# Is PUB $ \Longrightarrow $ CGT still an open problem?

Tags: functional-analysis

Closed graph theorem says ' A closed operator between Banach spaces is continuous'.

Principle of uniform boundedness says ' If $V$ is Banach and $W$ is a normed space, then pointwise bounded family of continuous operators between them is uniformly bounded.'

I know the following implications:

1. CGT $\Longrightarrow$ PUB.
2. If we assume $V$ and $W$ to be Hilbert spaces in the statement of CGT, then we have PUB $\Longrightarrow$ CGT.

But, I don't know if there is proof of 'PUB $\Longrightarrow$ CGT' with as it is statement (i.e. without extra assumptions). I couldn't find it online.

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/190587/87850) question at mathoverflow. The answer gives a proof of the open mapping theorem from the uniform boundedness theorem (which is sufficient since OMT is equivalent to CGT). Further, that answer is based on a direct proof of PUB implies CGT and gives a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much !